# How to print two column dataset from csv files in python ubuntu

Tags: python, csv

I have csv data files which contain 13 column. I want to split two column values and another to add one more column.

```
def rowfilter(col1, col2):
    try:
        csv_read = csv.reader(open('items.csv'), delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_read:
        print(row[int(cols[0]):int(cols[1])])  
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found")

    inputrows = input("Enter columns in the format: col1 col2 ")

    rowfilter(inputrows.split()))
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: I want to print the two column data from the multi column csv file.

Answer (score 0):

To work with csvs, usually the easiest way is to use the [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) module. It offers easy to use I/O, selection and manipulation interfaces.

```
def rowfilter(col1, col2):
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv('items.csv')

        print(df[[col1, col2]])  
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found")

    inputrows = input("Enter columns in the format: col1 col2 ")

    rowfilter(inputrows.split()))
```

This will print the columns.